# Cisco administrative distance 255

Tags: cisco, routing

On Cisco gear the maximum administrative distance for a route is 255. This makes the route [unusable](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/15986-admin-distance.html#topic2).

> If the administrative distance is 255, the router does not believe the source of that route and does not install the route in the routing table.

Is there any practical use in configuring a route with an administrative distance of 255?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the following link states it usage

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/4170-ospfprocesses.html

As per the link it helps in preventing routing loops by denying the routes to installed within the routing table..(In case of redistribution in OSPF)
Please have a look at the link, it has an illustrated example.

Hope it helps Thanks

Comment: So according to the doc, it is (or was) a method of controlling redistribution before route-maps were implemented.